# Is it possible to wrap http.ServeHttp in go to add sessions using alexedwards/scs/v2

Tags: go, http, session

I am trying to add sessions to an existing http server written in go. I have code like the following

```
type HttpServer struct {
    getRoutes  map[string]http.HandlerFunc // pattern => handler
    postRoutes map[string]http.HandlerFunc
    server     http.Server
}
func (s *HttpServer) Run() {
    address := "127.0.0.1:8080"
    s.server = http.Server{
        Addr:           address,
        Handler:        s,
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }
    log.Fatal(s.server.ListenAndServe())
}
func (s *HttpServer) ServeHTTP(writer http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     ...
}
```

I would like to add sessions using
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/alexedwards/scs/v2#SessionManager.LoadAndSave

The example code in the link is

```
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/put", putHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/get", getHandler)

    // Wrap your handlers with the LoadAndSave() middleware.
    http.ListenAndServe(":4000", sessionManager.LoadAndSave(mux))
```

The example code passes mux into LoadAndSave, then passes the new handler into http.ListenAndServe(port, newHandler). In my case the handler comes from a ServeHttp method I added to the *HttpServer struct. The handler in the example case comes from the mux.

I am new to go. Is it possible to pass my ServeHTTP method into LoadAndSave and use the handler returned from LoadAndSave? If not, is there a way to pass the http.Server struct fields used in my example into http.ListenAndServe(Port, handler)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603316/peter)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76606255/6309), the `LoadAndSave()` method from `alexedwards/scs/v2` expects an [`http.Handler` interface](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Handler) as an argument.
Since your `HttpServer` type has a `ServeHTTP` method with the correct signature, it satisfies the `http.Handler` interface, and you can pass an instance of your `HttpServer` type to the `LoadAndSave` method.

But your `Run()` method should have a `sessionManager *scs.SessionManager` as parameter:

```golang
func (s *HttpServer) Run(sessionManager *scs.SessionManager) {
    address := "127.0.0.1:8080"
    
    // Wrap your HttpServer with the LoadAndSave middleware.
    handlerWithSessions := sessionManager.LoadAndSave(s)
    
    ...
}
```

That means creating and configuring the `SessionManager` *outside* this method (with [scs.New()](https://github.com/alexedwards/scs/blob/10d4299e3b245836e258e3eb7aa1c60ee9732845/session.go#L97-L99)), and passing it in when you call `Run`.
There, you can set `sessionManager` as a field in the `HttpServer` struct.
That will allow your `(s *HttpServer) ServeHTTP(writer http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)` to retrieve it.

For instance:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/alexedwards/scs/v2"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type HttpServer struct {
    getRoutes     map[string]http.HandlerFunc // pattern => handler
    postRoutes    map[string]http.HandlerFunc
    server        http.Server
    sessionManager *scs.SessionManager
}

func (s *HttpServer) Run(sessionManager *scs.SessionManager) {
    address := "127.0.0.1:8080"
    
    // Set the sessionManager field
    s.sessionManager = sessionManager
    
    // Wrap your HttpServer with the LoadAndSave middleware.
    handlerWithSessions := sessionManager.LoadAndSave(s)
    
    s.server = http.Server{
        Addr:           address,
        Handler:        handlerWithSessions, // Use the wrapped handler
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }
    
    log.Fatal(s.server.ListenAndServe())
}

func (s *HttpServer) ServeHTTP(writer http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Access the session via the sessionManager field
    session := s.sessionManager.Load(r)
    
    // Use the session, e.g. session.Put, session.Get, etc.
    // ...
}

func main() {
    // Create and configure the session manager
    sessionManager := scs.New()
    sessionManager.Lifetime = 24 * time.Hour
    
    // Create your custom HttpServer
    httpServer := &HttpServer{
        getRoutes:  make(map[string]http.HandlerFunc),
        postRoutes: make(map[string]http.HandlerFunc),
    }
    
    // Start the server with the session manager
    httpServer.Run(sessionManager)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. *HttpServer implements the http.Handler interface so you can pass it to LoadAndSave:

```
func (s *HttpServer) Run() {
    address := "127.0.0.1:8080"
    s.server = http.Server{
        Addr:           address,
        Handler:        sessionManager.LoadAndSave(s),
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }
    log.Fatal(s.server.ListenAndServe())
}
```