# Simple test for alexedwards/scs using only the public api

Tags: go, http, testing, session

This question is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76606201/is-it-possible-to-wrap-http-servehttp-in-go-to-add-sessions-using-alexedwards-sc). I would like a simple test for https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/alexedwards/scs/v2@v2.5.1 to verify the functions I would like to use. Basically, I just want to put some data into the session, pull it out, and verify it is the same. Something like:

```
func TestScs_SetGetIsSame1(t *testing.T) {
    sessionManager := scs.New()
    req := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
    key := "boolean"
    expected := false
    sessionManager.Put(req.Context(), key, expected)
    actual := sessionManager.GetBool(req.Context(), key)
    assert.Equal(t, expected, actual)
}
```

This gives panic: scs: no session data in context.

I tried copying the [example from the httptest package](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest#example-Server), but httptest.Server does not implement  http.Handler (missing method ServeHTTP).

```
func TestScs_SetGetIsSame2(t *testing.T) {
    sessionManager := scs.New()

    ts := httptest.NewServer((http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello, client")
        expected := true
        sessionManager.Put(r.Context(), "key", expected)
        actual := sessionManager.GetBool(r.Context(), "key")
        assert.Equal(t, expected, actual)
    })))
    defer ts.Close()

    res, err := http.Get(ts.URL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    greeting, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s", greeting)

    sessionManager.LoadAndSave(ts)
}
```

I also looked at the [tests in the alexedwards/scs repository](https://github.com/alexedwards/scs/blob/master/data_test.go#L484), but they use a private function addSessionDataToContext.

What is the best, most simple way to test sessions in go?

Comment: I have edited the answer and updated the code to better reflect your example (your second block of code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your code

```golang
ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // ...
}))

sessionManager.LoadAndSave(ts) // this line is incorrect
```

You are trying to pass the test server (`ts`) to `sessionManager.LoadAndSave`. This will not work because `sessionManager.LoadAndSave` expects an `http.Handler`, and `ts` is of type `*httptest.Server`, not `http.Handler`.

Instead, you should pass the actual handler to [`sessionManager.LoadAndSave`](https://github.com/alexedwards/scs/blob/10d4299e3b245836e258e3eb7aa1c60ee9732845/session.go#L126-L129) before creating the test server.

For that, you would wrap the actual handler function with `sessionManager.LoadAndSave` (which does return a `http.Handler`) before passing it to `httptest.NewServer`.

```golang
handler := sessionManager.LoadAndSave(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // ... logic here ...
}))

ts := httptest.NewServer(handler)
```

That creates a new handler by wrapping your actual handler function with the `sessionManager.LoadAndSave` middleware. This wrapped handler is then passed to `httptest.NewServer`.

If you bring it all together:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/alexedwards/scs/v2"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func TestScs_SetGetIsSame2(t *testing.T) {
    sessionManager := scs.New()

    // Create a handler and wrap it using sessionManager.LoadAndSave
    handler := sessionManager.LoadAndSave(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello, client")
        expected := true
        sessionManager.Put(r.Context(), "key", expected)
        actual := sessionManager.GetBool(r.Context(), "key")
        assert.Equal(t, expected, actual)
    }))

    // Create a test server with the handler
    ts := httptest.NewServer(handler)
    defer ts.Close()

    // Make a request to the server
    res, err := http.Get(ts.URL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Read the response body
    greeting, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Print the response body
    fmt.Printf("%s", greeting)
}
```